# Could not cast value of type UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, tableview

I have a little problem I have custom cell at `cellTableView` with identifier `cell` when I run app I get err. How can I repair it?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you sure you have setup the cell reuseIdentifier correctly?

Comment: There are (currently) 34 questions for `[swift] could not cast value of type uitableviewcell` ...

Comment: @MartinR I try 1st site of google. not work :/

Comment: Is `cellTableViewCell` a subclass of `UITableViewCell`?  From that error it sounds like it isn't...

Comment: @creeperspeak no it isn't

Comment: @Naiwi That is your problem.  You can't force cast `UITableViewCell` as `cellTableViewCell` if it is not a subclass.

Comment: @creeperspeak Thanks work! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you created a custom class for your custom cell, i.e. `cellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {...}`, then make sure you set the cell's class name using the Identity Inspector to properly identify it.

Image example:

[image: Setting the Cell's Custom Class]

Comment: I had it [link](https://scr.hu/NLq8yJ)

Comment: @Naiwi Ok good.  Have you created a separate Swift file for the custom class? For example, cellTableViewCell.swift

Comment: yes i have cellTableViewCell.swift

Comment: Glad you got it working, @Naiwi.  For future reference, your custom cell MUST be a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: but can I do it when I have another file or not?

Comment: @Naiwi, No, you need the file to define your custom swift class. Otherwise, the compiler wouldn't know what you are talking about! Alternatively, you could have defined it as a struct.

Comment: struct I will see with it later too ;)! Thanks a lot